# Ionic 2 project. Deps unconsultancies

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs5

I worked on Ionic 2 project 2 months ago. Now I reinstalled my machine and tried to start my project again.
I pulled my code but I get the following error when I try to "ionic serve" my project.

I am pretty shire that this is some library version problem. But I am unable to resolve it.

The errors I get are:

---

```
[21:52:08]  typescript: node_modules/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.d.ts, line: 20 
        Class 'NavControllerBase' incorrectly implements interface 'NavController'. Types of property 'popTo' are 
        incompatible. Type '(indexOrViewCtrl: any, opts?: NavOptions, done?: Function) => Promise<any>' is not 
        assignable to type '(page: any, params?: any, opts?: NavOptions, done?: Function) => Promise<any>'. Types of 
        parameters 'done' and 'opts' are incompatible. Type 'NavOptions' is not assignable to type 'Function'. 
        Property 'apply' is missing in type 'NavOptions'. 

  L20:  export declare class NavControllerBase extends Ion implements NavController {
  L21:      parent: any;
```

[21:52:08]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts, line: 16 
            Class 'Subject' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable'. Types of property 'lift' are 
            incompatible. Type '(operator: Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type 
            '(operator: Operator) => Observable'. Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 
            'Observable'. Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.

```
  L16:  export declare class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements ISubscription {
  L17:      observers: Observer<T>[];
```

[21:52:08]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts, line: 23 
            Class 'WebSocketSubject' incorrectly extends base class 'AnonymousSubject'. Types of property 'lift' 
            are incompatible. Type '(operator: Operator) => WebSocketSubject' is not assignable to type '(operator: Operator) => Observable'. Type 'WebSocketSubject' is not assignable to type 
            'Observable'. Types of property 'operator' are incompatible. Type 'Operator' is not assignable to 
            type 'Operator'. Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'T'.

```
  L23:  export declare class WebSocketSubject<T> extends AnonymousSubject<T> {
  L24:      url: string;
```

[21:52:08]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/